# No module named 'pandas' in Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, module, pycharm, sklearn-pandas

I read all the topics about, but I cannot solve my problem:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/.../.../.../reading_data.py", line 1, in <module>
 import pandas as pd
 ImportError: No module named pandas
```

This is my environment:

Ubuntu 14.04

Pycharm version: 2016.1.4

Python version: 2.7.10

Pandas version: 0.18.1

Pandas works in Anaconda, in Jupyter too. How to fix the problem?

Comment: See [PyCharm: Configure a Python interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) and click the dropdown at the top left of the page for all versions back to 2017.1.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you select the project interpreter for your current project?
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html

follow this link, check whether pandas listed in the packages.

Comment: The OP should make sure that Anaconda is the selected interpreter. That environment will include Pandas.

Comment: Works a treat: 
From the PyCharm menu system: File -> Settings Project: YourProjectName -> Project Interpreter -> Select from the drop down list and choose Anaconda and click OK. (It may take a few moments to update in background).

Comment: If anyone is looking for an updated pycharm 2019 answer:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: I changed the interpreter to Anaconda, still I am getting the same error, no module named pandas, though it is there installed in the system

Answer (score 2):

you can add a new  project interpreter if you are using PyCharm ( IDE) . I install Anaconda first.

1) go to File and click on Setting 
2) go to project XXX  ( right below Version Control)
3) click project interpreter 
4) click the top right  button ( lined up with project interpreter )

[add new project interpreter - Anaconda3/python.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JO0j.png)

[add new project interpreter - Anaconda3/python.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ashn1.png)

Answer (score 0):

YOu are missing the libraries / Packages should be included in your project interpreter. add the libraries there all will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to delete some __init__.py files in sub folders, e.g. src/site/__init__.py

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Windows OS-PyCharm
Even though Pandas are installed and work well when executed from Python IDLE, somehow they were not visible in Pycharm. This has to do with the vm in Pycharm and libraries not visible. To resolve this issue:
Open Py script in pycharm add first line of code - import pandas as pd
Highlight and Right click on the word pandas in that line - Show Context Actions - Install Pandas

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).