# No module named 'pandas' in PyCharm, but module is installed

Tags: python, pandas, import, pycharm, conda

I have a project in PyCharm in which a `.py` file imports `pandas`, but in the Context Actions the message

> No module named 'pandas'

appears, although I do have `pandas` 1.3.0 installed in my `venv` as you can see in the picture below. What could be the reason for this?

[Pandas installed, but no module found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tckZv.jpg)

In the Terminal tab of PyCharm I can actually import `pandas`, but in the Python Console tab I can't.

[Terminal tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9b3t.png)

[Python Console tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1nuy.png)

Comment: what is your interpreter in PyCharm project? File->Settings->Project Interpreter, is it the venv you want?

Comment: See if the following helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376351/no-module-named-pandas-in-pycharm

Comment: @DaSong I have selected my Conda Interpreter and in the package list `pandas` does appear. That's what you mean? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: double check with the following in your terminal: `conda env list`, then choose the env, `conda activate your_env`, then start python and import pandas