# python won't recognize Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, runtime-error

I have python 3.10.4 installed and running perfectly fine, but was given a bigger assignment that seems best suited for pandas.  I installed PyCharm (2022.1 Community edition, v11.0.14.1) and that seems to work fine.

I did all the steps to install pandas (ver 1.4.2) and it seems to be in place but no matter what I do as soon as I import it in to my program
`import pandas as pd`

I get the error:
`no module named pandas`

while in PyCharm, I do have the pandas package in place for the current project, but nothing seems to be working

Comment: I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376351/no-module-named-pandas-in-pycharm) but it is from 2016. Does following the accepted answer resolve your issue?

Comment: It's important to specify the environments you are using. Most IDEs (like PyCharm) have their own installation of Python.  Installing `pandas` there will not make it available to the command-line Python installation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with either interpreter or run configuration.

Let's elaborate on that, shall we?

First of all check at the bottom if you have a python interpreter associated with your current project:
[I have a venv python environment associated with the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwoVY.png)

If you do too then perform these steps:

1. Click on it and then select interpreter settings
2. It will take you to the Interpreter Settings screen and you will be able to check all the installed packages in the associated (venv) environment or System python interpreter, depending on what is associated with your project.
3. Nonetheless, check if you have pandas installed in the list if not use "+" button to do so.

Run Configuration:

1. If in the above steps you found out that pandas was already installed, that means you are using the wrong environment in "run configuration"
2. From the drop-down select edit configuration, and select the configuration you are trying to run.
   [Edit Run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6myO.png)
3. You will see an option "Python Interpreter", using the drop down use the same python (exact same name from the previous step) you checked in the previous step which was having pandas installed. Apply/OK and try to run script again.